# AJAX POST to PHP without JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I had a PHP assignment that I decided that I wanted to try and add AJAX to because in our class we will not learn AJAX just PHP. I can't seem to get the response to work. However in the network section of my console on Fire Fox I can find the POST send with the values I entered into the form and the PHP echo as a result from the php function working. But, it will not show up in my div tag. Any help would be most welcome, thanks.

Here is the HTML and JavaScript:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function testPass() {
            var username = document.getElementById("uname").value;
            var passwrd = document.getElementById("passwd").value;
            var creds = "uname="+username+"&passwd="+passwrd;
            var ajx = new XMLHttpRequest();
            ajx.onreadystatechagne = function () {
                if (ajx.readyState == 4 && ajx.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = ajx.responseText;
                }
            };
            ajx.open("POST", "authenticate.php", true);
            ajx.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            ajx.send(creds);
            //document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = creds;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        <form id="login">
            <strong>Login</strong><br/><br/>
            Username :<br/><input type="text" id="uname"><br/>
            Password :<br/><input type="text" id="passwd"><br/><br/>
            <div id="message" style="color:red;"></div>
            <br/><button type="button" value="Submit" onclick="testPass();">Sign In</button>
        </form>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the PHP:

```
<?php
$uname = $_POST['uname'];
$passwd = $_POST['passwd'];

if (empty($uname) && empty($passwd)) {
    echo "The username and password are required!";
} else if (empty($uname)) {
    echo "The username is required!";
} else if (empty($passwd)) {
    echo "The password is required!";
} else {
    echo "It works!";
} ?>
```

Comment: You can see the request, but no response?

Comment: Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo : `ajx.onreadystatechagne` should be `ajx.onreadystatechange`

Comment: Instead of just pointing out a spelling error, it doesn't hurt to explain how he could resolve these kind of issues in the future.

Comment: Fair point, but beside proof reading the code, it's hard to tell, as JavaScript won't output error when assigning value to the wrong key.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use functions as much as possible to make code reusable and easier to troubleshoot. I suggest the following code.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function createAjaxRequestObject() {
            var xmlhttp;

            if(window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else { // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }

            // Create the object
            return xmlhttp;
        }

        function AjaxPost(ajaxURL, parameters, onComplete) {
            var http3 = createAjaxRequestObject();

            http3.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if(http3.readyState == 4) {
                    if(http3.status == 200) {
                        if(onComplete) {
                            onComplete(http3.responseText);
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            // Create parameter string
            var parameterString = "";
            var isFirst = true;
            for(var index in parameters) {
                if(!isFirst) {
                    parameterString += "&";
                } 
                parameterString += encodeURIComponent(index) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(parameters[index]);
                isFirst = false;
            }

            // Make request
            http3.open("POST", ajaxURL, true);
            http3.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            http3.send(parameterString);
        }

        function completedAJAX(response) {
            alert(response);
        }

        function testPass() {
            var parameters = {
              "uname" : document.getElementById("uname").value,
              "passwd" : document.getElementById("passwd").value
            };

            AjaxPost("authenticate.php", parameters, completedAJAX);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        <form id="login">
            <strong>Login</strong><br/><br/>
            Username :<br/><input type="text" name="uname" id="uname" /><br/>
            Password :<br/><input type="password" name="passwd" id="passwd" /><br/><br/>
            <div id="message" style="color:red;"></div>
            <br/><button type="button" value="Submit" onclick="testPass();">Sign In</button>
        </form>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Another tip is to use Firebug if you are using Firefox or the developers tools in Chrome (Press CTRL + SHIFT + J) when testing some scripts. This error would have popped up in the console and you would immediately noticed the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you already solved it
but here is solution 
ajx.onreadystatechagne

should be

ajx.onreadystatechange